# How to reduce or organize swagger declarations with Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kotlin

how can I organize the swagger annotations, for example I have an endpoint that catches all the users, so the swagger statements were huge. Is there any way I can organize this in another file to be more organized?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of strategies often used is creating an interface (e.g. `PersonApi` in your case) and moving all swagger annotations there. The actual controller should implement this interface.

In regard to the error responses: you may consider adding them programatically to all operations/endpoints using [OpenApiCustomiser](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/381#issuecomment-579583870).